# Internet Public ip address and django static file in pdf

Tags: django, nginx, weasyprint

I used django and weasyprint to make an application which print a pdf file with picture and css file which design my pdf file. I used nginx, gunicorn and supervisor to deploy my application. In my intranet all is ok. When i used INTERNET PUBLIC IP ADDRESS to publish it on internet, my pdf file don't show anymore picture and css design. but all the application's static files work well
I see my gunicorn log but nothing. 
I use Nginx to serve my static file. this the configuration

> upstream app_server {
>      server unix:/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
>   }
>
> server {
>
> listen   80;
>
> server_name 127.0.0.1;
>
> client_max_body_size 4G;
>
> access_log /webapps/myapp/logs/nginx-access.log;
>
> error_log /webapps/myapp/logs/nginx-error.log;
>
> location /static/ 
>        {
>          alias   /webapps/myapp/basegenecirdes/public/static/;
>      }
>
> location /media/ {
>          alias   /webapps/myapp/media/;
>      }
>
> location / {
>          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>          proxy_redirect off;
>
> ```
>    if (!-f $request_filename) {
>        proxy_pass http://app_server;
>        break;
>    }
> ```
>
> }

in my views.py to call a pdf file, i use this

> html = render_to_string('pdf/print.html', {'pagesize':'A4'})
>   response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf",)
>   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="print.pdf"' 
>   weasyprint.HTML(string=html,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(response)
>   return response

static image file:

```
<img style="background-color: white" src="{% static "image/photo_50x48.png" %}">
```

media image file

```
<img alt="{{ a.nom }}" src="{{ a.photo.thumbnail.url }}" >
```

is somebody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your edits, this question appears to be a duplicate of [PDF output using Weasyprint not showing images (Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988707/pdf-output-using-weasyprint-not-showing-images-django)

You have the first part of the answer already in your code.  But I don't see this part in your `write_pdf()` call:

> For the HTML styles to show on the PDF, add presentational_hints=True as per the Weasyprint docs:
>
> `pdf = html.write_pdf(stylesheets=[CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT +  '/css/detail_pdf_gen.css')], presentational_hints=True);`

Comment: thank you it is working, just picture d'ont appear, i update my post to show you how i put img html code in my pdf

Comment: any help? Since 3 days, i am on this problem.

Comment: how can i enable looging? i will put it after "return response"?

Comment: To enable logging you’ll have to set it up in settings and then call getLogger() in the file before writing to it. This explains how to do it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: i got 2 logs  Failed to load stylesheet at http://IP_ADDR/static/css/default.css : HTTPError: HTTP Error 401:  Failed to load image at "http://IP_ADDR/static/image/picture_50x48.png" (HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: )