# django http Error 401 for css and picture on pdf

Tags: django, nginx, weasyprint

I used `django` and `weasyprint` to make an application which print a `pdf` file with picture and `css` file which design my `pdf` file.

A log in `django` gives me this:

```
Failed to load stylesheet at "http://IP_ADDR/static/css/default.css" : HTTPError: HTTP Error 401:
Failed to load image at "http://IP_ADDR/static/image/picture_50x48.png" (HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Among other things (what have you tried), this question is missing a question..

Comment: I do All this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681096/internet-public-ip-address-and-django-static-file-in-pdf/51681534?noredirect=1#comment90512402_51681534

Comment: Well, googling error 401 says that you need authentication to access the resource requested. Do you have problem with all your assets in /static/?

Comment: No problem in particular because in my intranet all is working.

Comment: @Hervé check permissions of folders/files in your production server.

Comment: @guillermochamorro ls -la on the static folder give **drwxrwxrwx** for the entire project **drwxrwxr-x**

Comment: It is possible that it was a NAT problem? beauce a have made a NAT between Internet addresse with my internal adress?